# How to download a .deb package?

Tags: software-installation, libreoffice, deb

[This server](http://downloadarchive.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/old/3.5.7.2/deb/x86_64/) has a .deb package that I want to download. The issue is, it only lets me download one file at a time from within the package. How can I download just the .deb file to install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deb file has been compressed, I downloaded and extracted the largest archive as follows:

```
wget http://downloadarchive.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/old/3.5.7.2/deb/x86_64/LibO_3.5.7rc2_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz
tar xvf LibO_3.5.7rc2_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz
```

This extraction creates a directory structure:

```
LibO_3.5.7rc2_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-US/DEBS
```

and all of the deb packages are in this 'DEBS' folder:

```
andrew@corinth:~/LibO_3.5.7rc2_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-US/DEBS$ ls
desktop-integration
libobasis3.5-base_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-binfilter_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-calc_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-core01_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-core02_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-core03_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-core04_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-core05_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-core06_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-core07_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-draw_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-en-us_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-en-us-base_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-en-us-calc_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-en-us-math_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-en-us-res_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-en-us-writer_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-extension-beanshell-script-provider_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-extension-javascript-script-provider_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-extension-mediawiki-publisher_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-extension-nlpsolver_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-extension-pdf-import_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-extension-presentation-minimizer_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-extension-presenter-screen_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-extension-python-script-provider_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-extension-report-builder_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-gnome-integration_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-graphicfilter_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-images_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-impress_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-javafilter_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-kde-integration_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-math_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-ogltrans_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-onlineupdate_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-ooofonts_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-ooolinguistic_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-postgresql-sdbc_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-pyuno_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-writer_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libobasis3.5-xsltfilter_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libreoffice3.5_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libreoffice3.5-base_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libreoffice3.5-calc_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libreoffice3.5-dict-en_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libreoffice3.5-dict-es_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libreoffice3.5-dict-fr_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libreoffice3.5-draw_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libreoffice3.5-en-us_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libreoffice3.5-impress_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libreoffice3.5-math_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libreoffice3.5-stdlibs_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libreoffice3.5-ure_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
libreoffice3.5-writer_3.5.7-2_amd64.deb
andrew@corinth:~/LibO_3.5.7rc2_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-US/DEBS$
```

And then if you wish you can install *all* of these from within the DEBS directory by running:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Installing any of these could be an issue depending on:

1. Which version of Ubuntu you are using
2. Which particular deb package you are trying to install

Dependencies being the main issue as well as more modern versions being already available / installed from the Ubuntu repository...

Comment: whoops, sorry, i gave the wrong link. I would like to download this, which for some reason, does not work even with your edited command http://downloadarchive.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/old/3.5.7.2/deb/x86_64/  It gives an error 404

Comment: You are after LibreOffice itself? That would be this file:  LibO_3.5.7rc2_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz

Comment: sorry, i'm now getting confused with how to edit the commands. Could you please edit your answer to include the correct source?

Comment: specifically the last command- I don't know what the right filepath should be for 3.5.7.2

Comment: I double guessed the correct archive and I have altered my answer :)

Comment: On the first command, it says "no such file or directory" though, i know it exists in nautilus

Comment: Commands are correct but you can open the archive by double clicking it, then the Archive Manager will open it for you

Comment: yes, i got that, but the issue is how to install all of those deb packages that all depend on each other

Comment: Try: `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` from within the DEBS folder

Comment: awesome, thank you- that seems to have worked. The odd thing is that libreoffice isn't installed...

Comment: whoops, nevermind. forgot the desktop-integration folder. worked like a charm. Thank you so much for your time

Comment: Good to hear it all worked out :)

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to use the `apt-get` `download` command:

`apt-get download mypackage1 mypackage2`

[Original Link](https://superuser.com/a/530371/305749)

Comment: After the downloading is finished,  you will have the relevant .deb files under your current directory.  In the term of  the content of them, they are the same as the ones if you have installed them or are going to install them by apt install  mypackage1 mypackage2.